# Does XPathDocument use the memory stream it is constructed with after construction?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose

I have code like this:

```
// Take the xml message and turn it into an object
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

XPathDocument xPathDocument = new XPathDocument(memoryStream);
```

I realized that I don't clean up the `MemoryStream` anywhere.  I was just going to change it to this:

```
// Take the xml message and turn it into an object
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

XPathDocument xPathDocument;
using(memoryStream)
{
    xPathDocument = new XPathDocument(memoryStream);
}
```

But I was not sure if `XPathDocument` uses the `MemoryStream` internally after construction.  (If so, I would need to wait and dispose it after I am all done with the `XPathDocument`.)

Does anyone know when I can dispose this `MemoryStream`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No that's a good change. Once the stream is loaded into the xml, you don't need it any more.

Well I hope it's good, it's remarkably similar to a lot of the code I've written. :D

Answer (score 4):

The entire Stream is read and load and so yes, you can Dispose the MemoryStream this way.

On the other hand, a MemoryStream doesn't really need to be Disposed, it's more the general principal. If it had been a FileStream or NetworkStream the `using` would have been critical.

Comment: Hmm, just a good habit really, and a lot of the stuff we write, does come from FileStream ora cloned stream. Using using is now as automatic for me in .net, as Try Finally is in Delphi. It won't hurt anywhere nears as much as forgetting to dispose of something you should have is the way we look at it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the memorystream with using block anyway, it is better to limit the scope of the variable to the using block, that way you can be sure it will not be used outside of it, like this:

```
using (var memorystream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    xPathDocument = new XPathDocument(memoryStream);
}
```